# HP RAID-0 expand on DL180G6

Tags: raid, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, expansion

There's HP DL180G6 Server with HP Smart Array P410 controller. Server running MySQL on Debian Linux with ext4 fs. HPACUCLI utilities (ACU CLI Version: 9.40.12.0) are installed.

There's 4 HDD Seagate 600GB in RAID 10 array. I want add 2 more HDDs to this array and expand it without data loss, reinstalling all and downtiming server. Can this be done such way?

Comment: Presumably you've read the documentation on how to do this and you've ran into a problem with this regular process right? if so then let us know what problems you're having please. On the other hand if you just can't be bothered putting in a moment's research yourself first then I think you've come to the wrong place, we expect users on this site to have put some degree of effort in before asking on here.

Comment: OFC I'm reading docs on question, f.e.:  http://www.sbsfaq.com/?p=1662&doing_wp_cron=1532675502.2238080501556396484375 - it explains all rather briefly. The question mainly is anybody has PRACTICAL experience in live RAID expansion under linux using HP CLI utils? Docs are good, but if there any nuances, that somebody had during procedure...

Answer (score 3):

BWC must be configured and battery must be charged before expanding it on a fly.

Also, backup data first and then try to expand the array.

- As per ext4 expansion -
  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/ext4grow
- As per Smart Array expansion -
  https://community.hpe.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/Dl380G6-RAID-10-Expand/td-p/4770620